# Silverlight 4 Printing API

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, printing

Within Silverlight 4 printing with the printing API will it "auto-scroll" covered areas?
Excuse me if I'm not using the right terminology. For example, If I have a DataGrid and it has 10 items shown and 40 not revealved (but you could scroll to). Is there a way to print the whole DataGrid, rather than just the "screen shot" view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the term you're looking for is "paginate". And no, Silverlight will not auto-paginate data grid or any other controls for you. You will have to prepare your data for printing your self.

Comment: also pay attention to the HasMorePages property